# How to setup update on cascade in hibernate 4 with javax.persistence.OneToMany?

Tags: java, hibernate, hibernate-cascade

I use hibernate 4.2.

It doesn't give me hibernate variant of OneToMany annotation, but only `javax.persistence.OneToMany`.

So I use it as

```
public class Parent  {
      ...........
    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "parent", fetch = FetchType.LAZY, cascade = { CascadeType.PERSIST, CascadeType.MERGE })
        private Set<Child> children = new HashSet<Child>();
```

When I do update of Parent I expect children collection to be updated by cascade MERGE.

```
session.update(parent);
```

But it doesn't update Child entities of children collection. It only sends update statement for Parent entity.

So how can I update on cascade Child entities of `children` collection?

I cannot use `org.hibernate.annotations.CascadeType` because it is not supported by javax.persistence.OneToMany.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want to use hibernate's `CascadeType`, define `@Cascade(..)` separately on field/method level,

```
@OneToMany(mappedBy = "parent", fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
@Cascade({CascadeType.PERSIST, CascadeType.MERGE, CascadeType.SAVE_UPDATE}) //example
private Set<Child> children = new HashSet<Child>();
```

Answer (score 1):

Instead of persist or merge did you try with all?.

```
   @OneToMany(orphanRemoval = true, cascade = {CascadeType.ALL}, fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
```

Try it just in case that you want to remove this child in case that the father would be removed.

In my example works